# Extension to translate words in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, translation

How can I translate words in Google Chrome?

Are there any add-ons or extensions for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes,you can find it here:
http://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb

Comment: I've been using this for a while, it's really good. But that question shouldn't even exist - it was quite easy to find this just searching on chrome itself.

Comment: From the description of the extension, it only translates whole pages. I expected something like the other answer (auto-translate).

Answer (score 0):

I used Instant Translate, it is so simple with pronunciation.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/instant-translate/ihmgiclibbndffejedjimfjmfoabpcke/related?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

[Ddict](http://ddict.me) is a google translate for browser, give it a try